# Can’t remember password for MySQL on macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, passwords, mysql

Please help me in step by step setting up MySQL with the help of terminal, I guess I don’t remember the password or I messed up with things. I get the following message and I don’t remember the password

```
jaychavan@Jays-Air ~ % cd /usr/local/mysql
jaychavan@Jays-Air mysql % cd /usr/local/mysql
jaychavan@Jays-Air mysql % sudo bin/mysql_secure_installation

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MySQL
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none):
```

Comment: How did you install it? When did you install it? Do you know what version you installed?

Comment: i guess thies 5.5.48

Comment: Have you searched "recover MySQL root password"?